# Accessing internal/external memory in android

Tags: android

I am pretty new to android programming and I need your help in proceeding further in my application. I wanted to access the internal or external memory of android phones through my application with both write and read permissions. I wanted to give users a choice as to which memory to be used in the application.

I'll be thankful to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Add this to ur manifest to get Ext R-W permission - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For External storage
**Use this:**

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dirName" );
        if(!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdir();
            Log.i("Log", "folder created");
        }
```

This will create a folder with the name **dirName** into your **sdcard** . This means you get the access of the external storage by this **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()** method.

But for this you have to add the permission into your `menifest` file like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To check the sdCard is present in android device:

```
android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

Get the sd card's root directory:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

to store in to your phone memory into your package data folder:

```
String pathOfRoot = "/data/data/" + getPackageName();
```

Hope it will help you.